# Improve query performance when using regex with $and operator to search for multiple words in a string in mongodb Java driver

Tags: java, regex, mongodb-java

I am using mongodb Java driver to search a mongodb collection which is having more than 2000000 records. I am using regex with more than two search criteria in a single field. The query is taking more than 3 minutes. Is there a way to improve the query performance?

```
BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
regexQuery.put(
    "$and",
    Arrays.asList(
        new BasicDBObject(
            "REQUEST_XML",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "$regex",
                ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>" + ".*"
            )
        ),
        new BasicDBObject(
            "REQUEST_XML",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "$regex",
                ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>" + ".*"
            )
        )
    )
);
regexQuery.put("NAME", "Video");
```

Comment: The `.*M` parts are taking the most regex matching time. Do you really need a full string match? Remove `.*` at the start/end of both patterns.

Comment: Yes I need to find if two specific strings are present within an XML stored as a string in mongodb...

Comment: If you tell us what the source-data looks like, and what the search criteria are, then we can see if there is a fitting regex pattern. Right now we don't know either.

Comment: It's an XML document with more than 100 lines stored as a string in mongodb my search criteria is to find if the string <action>Add is present in two different areas in the XML

Comment: In order to construct a regex pattern we need to see what the target looks like, and what all the expected variations are.

Comment: Regex are not ment to be a XML query mechanism.....

Comment: My target is a String type column with an XML stored as String. Like below <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
.
.
.
.
.
<Details>
<action>Add</action>
.
.
.
.
<Main>
<action>Add</action>
.
.
.
</Request>   My expectation is if the above sections Main and Details have action code as "Add" it should be taken into count.